# nc of cygwin report connecting successed,even if the target ip address does not really exist

Tags: cygwin, netcat

I just installed the latest nc.exe 1.107-4 from cygwin on windows 7 platform.When lauched the command like:

`nc -vuz 10.31.28.188 6110`

,each time it reported connecting successed,even if the target ip
10.31.28.188 does not really exists.
Could someone tell what wrong with me?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you're asking nc to do the following:

1. Setup a socket to send data via UDP.

"-u" asks nc to use UDP, which is a connection-less protocol.

In this case, nc considers itself "connected" without exchanging any packets with it's peer, because it is ready to send data

2. Quit without sending any data.

"-z" tells nc not to send any data.

So, nc considers its work done, and reports success.

Comment: So,how could I determine whether a udp port of another machine is open or not?